# Склейка двух .exe

Tags: c#

У меня есть 2 .exe файла. Реально ли их склеить с помощью c#?

Comment: 2 любых файла можно склеить. Вопрос - зачем это вам нужно?

Comment: в целях саморазвития

Comment: В каком направлении вы хотите развиваться? Почему именно exe файлы?

Comment: потому что не .jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Окей, какой вопрос, такой ответ. Надо, так надо.

```cs
using var fs1 = File.OpenRead("file1.exe");
using var fs2 = File.OpenRead("file2.exe");
using var fs = File.Create("file1file2.bin");
fs1.CopyTo(fs);
fs2.CopyTo(fs);
```

Comment: спасибо за решение!

Comment: @ДенисСапфиров не за что, зеленая галочка слева от ответа :)

Comment: ограничение в 2 минуты, ждем

Comment: @ДенисСапфиров все забываю, что здесь 15 минут кулдаун принятия.

Comment: @ДенисСапфиров только учтите, чтобы вам их расклеить обратно, надо как минимум знать размер одного из них.

Comment: @ДенисСапфиров Склейка двух exe  по большей части бессмысленна. К тому же вариант простого (тупого) копирования сделает конечное exe неработоспособным.

Comment: @GarryGaller именно поэтому я пытался автору задавать уточняющие вопросы, но он дал понять, что не намерен на них отвечать, поэтому здесь решение "в лоб".

Comment: @aepot Ну я собственно свою реплику автору вопроса и адресую :-) Может быть это заставит его задуматься об осмысленных целях такой операций.   P.S. Адресацию поста исправил.

Comment: @aepot а оно не перепишет файл fs2 поверх fs1 ? Или оно аппендит бинарный контент? (нет возможности проверить, праздный интерес)

Comment: @Andrew fs1 и fs2 тут никак не связаны - копирование их контента идет в поток fs.  Что касается того, не перезапишет ли контент fs2 контент fs1 в потоке назначения fs, то судя по доке - нет.
Метод CopyTo объекта Stream не сбрасывает позицию записи в потоке  назначения после копирования: Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

Comment: Отличное решение :) легко поддерживать, ошибок минимум, расширяется на любые типы файлов. Жаль только, что это решение для бессмысленной задачи.